# In Ubuntu, does updating the CLASSPATH require a reboot?

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, path, bashrc

I changed my CLASSPATH and JAVA_HOME variable to something like this

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_24
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/tomcat/lib
export JAVA_HOME
```

And when I try to compile, the path in the CLASSPATH variable still does not seem to be recognized.  I either set the paths awkwardly or need to reboot.

Does what I did look right or is it somehow way off?  Should I try rebooting or is there some more obvious mistake in what I am doing?

Thanks,
Alex

Here are the compile errors:

package javax.servlet does not exist
    [javac] import javax.servlet.ServletException;

Comment: How do you start tomcat?

Comment: It started when I booted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If tomcat started when the machine booted, making changes to your .bashrc will do no good, since tomcat probably is not run by your user. If tomcat was installed from a .deb package, you could have a look in /etc/default/tomcat6, you will probably find similar variables there. Otherwise, we need to know more about how the start script looks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you "source" the file?

```
source /userdir/.bashrc (or whatever the specific filename is)
```

Either do that or re-login and the environment variables should be picked up.

Comment: @Quinn Just did the source command and it is still not picking up the lib directory :(

Comment: have you tried logging and logging out? what I do know right now is you shouldn't have to reboot :)

Comment: @Quinn yeah I tried even rebooting - still no luck

Comment: would need more data then.  Can you update the post with the messages indicating a different path during the compile?

Comment: @Quinn Just added the error example

Comment: thanks...so are you trying to compile code or start tomcat?  I was under the impression that it was the latter and now it seems like the former, which changes perspective.  I agree with Bittrance that if we are starting tomcat we are looking to see how it starts and that .bashrc isn't what we want to change.